# How do I get my program to separate not count the space between input as an integer?

Tags: c++

I am writing a very simple program with a do-while loop and I am having difficulty with a small thing in the input section. Whenever I prompt the user to enter two numbers to be added together it allows me to enter them but the program counts the space between the two numbers as an integer and it causes the program to end rather than continually looping. I know I can just make it:

```
cin >> num1;
cin >> num2;
```

but I like the way this looks much better and am wondering how to fix this problem? I hope I've been clear enough. It should be a pretty simple fix.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int num1,
        num2,
        sum;
    char repeat;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter two numbers to be added together: ";
        cin >> num1, num2;
        sum = num1 + num2;
        cout << "Your sum is " << sum << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to perform this operation again? (Y/N)";
        cin >> repeat;
    }
    while ((repeat == 'Y') || (repeat == 'y'));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try: `cin >> num1 >> num2;` instead of `cin >> num1, num2;`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the two numbers in a single `string`. Find the space position and split the input in two parts, like in the example.

NOTE: if you use c++11, the conversion to `int` can be made directly with `std::stoi(str)`

```
string input;
cin >> input;
int spacePos,
    num1,
    num2;

spacePos = input.find(" ");
num1 = atoi(input.substr(0, spacePos - 1).c_str());
num2 = atoi(input.substr(spacePos + 1).c_str());
```